# I have set php-mysql-apache to work on latin1 but when doing back-ups my character-set client is still utf8

Tags: php, mysql, apache, latin1

Yes, I know what you think, but for the moment we decided to go for latin1.

This is the mySQL config:
•   mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'character_set_%';
•   +--------------------------+--------+
•   | Variable_name            | Value  |
•   +--------------------------+--------+
•   | character_set_client     | latin1 |
•   | character_set_connection | latin1 |
•   | character_set_database   | latin1 |
•   | character_set_results    | latin1 |
•   | character_set_server     | latin1 |
•   | character_set_system     | utf8   |> This is impossible to change since it is a default system parameter.

For php we use the following commands at php.ini:
mssql.charset = "ISO-8859-1"

For apache the usual:
AddDefaultCharset ISO-8859-1

With all this everytime we do back up we get the following added to each table:
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;

/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;

Why the character_set_client is still in utf8 for connections between apache/php and mysql?

Comment: How do you back up your tables?

Comment: I am using mysqldump from the command line. This gives me a .sql type of file. When I open the .sql file I find the SET character_set_client = utf-8 on every table as described above... Very bizarre since all php, apache and mysql are latin1/iso-8859-1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

mysqldump doesn't look at your php or apache settings. You'll need to add the  `--default-character-set` flag when using mysqldump.

[From the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_default-character-set):

> --default-character-set=charset_name
>
> Use charset_name as the default
>   character set. See Section 9.5,
>   “Character Set Configuration”. If no
>   character set is specified, mysqldump
>   uses utf8, and earlier versions use
>   latin1.

Comment: This. How PHP connects to the tables won't matter to `mysqldump`, which is UTF-8 by default

Comment: Thanks bradym, this make senses since I have everything set to Latin1. I will keep an eye on the manual you linked to. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

if you notice carefully the directive in the php.ini you have set:

```
mssql.charset = "ISO-8859-1"
```

refers to `Microsoft SQL Server!` connections and not to `MySQL Server`.

jackman